Proof of Unique Factorisation of Polynomials over $\mathbb C$ by Identity Principle
Proposition: Any polynomial $p(x) = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ can be expressed uniquely as
$$
p(x) = a_n(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_n),
$$
where $r_1, r_2,\ldots, r_n$ (not necessarily distinct) are the roots of $p(x)$.
" Proof ":

Suppose all roots are distinct. Let $f(x) = a_n(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_n)$. Polynomials $p(x)$ and $f(x)$ have same set of roots. We notice that the leading the coefficient of $p(x)$ and $f(x)$ are equal, so $p(x)-f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$. But $p(x)-f(x)$ has $n$ distinct roots so, by identity principle, we get $p(x) = f(x)$.

Question: The issue with this proof is that it works only when all roots are distinct. If any some of the roots are equal then we won't be able to use identity principle. Please fix this proof or give alternative proof. Thanks in advance!
PS: Since Identity Principle is not quite standard name, so here I am quoting the theorem that I am referring Identity Principle:

A polynomial of degree at most $n$ with $n+1$ (or more) distinct roots vanishes identically.


Even when this argument does work it doesn't prove uniqueness of the factorization, only existence. And existence is easy to prove by induction on the fact that if $p(a) = 0$ then $x - a \mid p(x)$, which is a corollary of the Euclidean algorithm for polynomials, and can also be proven by replacing $p(x)$ with $p(x + a)$.

Uniqueness can be secured by remainder theorem, right?  I didn't mention it in my proof as I am more concerned about the factorisation.

Following my original answer, prashant sharma raised a question that revealed an oversight in my answer.  I have added an Addendum at the end of my answer to correct my oversight.

The following proof works just as well for $~z \in \Bbb{C},~$ as it does for $~x \in \Bbb{R}.$

The following assertion is sufficient:
Given any $~n$-th degree polynomial $~f(z)~$ in $~z \in \Bbb{C},~$  where $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}},$ such that $~f(r) = 0,~$ there exists a unique $~(n-1)$-th degree polynomial $~G(z)~$ in $~z \in \Bbb{C},~$ such that
$$f(z) = (z - r) \times G(z). \tag1 $$
Proof
Since $~f(r) = 0,~$ the function $~f(z)~$ may be re-expressed as $~f(z) - f(r).~$
This implies that
$$f(z) = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i(z^n - r^n).$$
Further, you have the following result (easily proven by induction)
that for all $~m \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$ that
$$z^m - r^m = (z - r) \times \\
\left[ ~z^{m-1} + z^{m-2}r + z^{m-3}r^2 + \cdots \\ + z^3r^{m-4} + z^2r^{m-3} + zr^{m-2} + r^{m-1}~\right]. $$
Given that the coefficients $~a_n, ~a_{n-1}, \cdots, a_0~$ are fixed, for each $~m~$ in $~\{2,3,\cdots,n\},~$ you can uniquely define
$$~G_m(z)  = a_m \times \\
= \left[ ~z^{m-1} + z^{m-2}r + z^{m-3}r^2 + \cdots \\ + z^3r^{m-4} + z^2r^{m-3} + zr^{m-2} + r^{m-1}~\right]. \tag2 $$
Edit
Also, define $~G_1(z) = a_1 \times 1.$
Then, uniquely define
$$~G(z) = \sum_{m = 1}^n G_m(z).$$
Further, in constructing $~G(z),~$ since the only term of degree $~(n-1)~$ is specifically represented by $~G_n(z),~$ you have that $~G(z)~$ is an $~(n-1)$-th degree polynomial.
Thus, there exists a unique polynomial $~G(z)~$ of degree $~(n-1)~$ such that
$$f(z) = (z-r) \times G(z).$$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
Addendum added to address an oversight in my original answer, as indicated by the following question/comment posted by prashant sharma, following my answer:

This is, in essence, a proof of factor theorem, right? How does it justify that the leading coefficient $~a_n~$
would be a factor?

I agree that the original answer does not address the above question.  This is my oversight, which is corrected below.
First of all, as I see it, while the analysis in my original answer does guarantee that $~a_n~$ is a factor in the specific function $~G_n(z),~$ it does not guarantee that $~a_n~$ is a factor in the constructed function $~G(z).~$
To correct this oversight, since you are guaranteed that $~a_n \neq 0,~$ take the preliminary step of re-expressing the coefficients:
$$b_k = \frac{a_k}{a_n} ~: ~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, n\} \implies b_n = 1.~$$
Then, you have that
$$f(z) = a_n \times \left[ ~\sum_{k=0}^n b_k z^k ~\right].$$
Since $~f(r) = 0,~$ this implies that $~f(z)~$ may be re-expressed as
$$f(z) - f(r) = a_n \times \left[ ~\sum_{i = 1}^n b_i(z^i - r^i) ~\right].$$
This implies that
$$\frac{f(z) - f(r)}{a_n} = \sum_{i = 1}^n b_i(z^i - r^i).$$
Then, all of the analysis in the original answer may be used to establish that
$$\frac{f(z) - f(r)}{a_n}$$
may be uniquely expressed as
$$(z - r) \times G(z).$$
Therefore, you have that
$$f(z) = a_n \times \frac{f(z) - f(r)}{a_n}$$
$$= a_n \times (z - r) \times G(z).$$

This is, in essence, a proof of factor theorem, right? How does it justify that the leading coefficient $a_n$ would be a factor?

@prashantsharma +1 to your comment, which catches an oversight in my original answer.  To correct this oversight, I have just added an Addendum to the end of my original answer.

There is one question on your updated answer: Suppose there is one more non-zero coefficient (for example, $a_1$) other than the leading coefficient. At what point your proof would breakdown if we take take $a_1$ common out instead of $a_n$?

@prashantsharma The analysis in the Addendum would also hold, if (for example) you were given that $~a_1 \neq 0,~$ and you wished to show (instead) that there exists an $~(n-1)$-th degree polynomial $~G(z)~$ such that $$f(z) = a_1 \times (z - r) \times G(z).$$  However, a critical point is that the only coefficient that you are guaranteed to be non-zero is $~a_n.~$  That is, this guarantee is based on the premise that $~f(z)~$ is an $~n$-th degree polynomial.  ...see next comment

Note also that the analysis demonstrates that $~G(z)~$ is an $~(n-1)$-th degree polynomial, so an inductive argument, where the degree of the trailing polynomial goes from $~n~$ to $~(n-1)~$ to $~(n-2) ~$ to $~\cdots~$ to $~1~$ will work.

So you are suggesting that we can pull out any any non-zero coefficient, right? But I think, this is not correct. If it were, then the same polynomial could be factorised in two different ways, that contradicts the uniqueness of factorisation.

@prashantsharma The uniqueness of factorisation is not contradicted, because the function $~G(z)~$ depends on which non-zero coefficient is pulled out.  Perhaps you might read the answer more carefully.
